# Using Python to open network settings in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python

I am trying to program a button that when pressed will open the network settings on the Raspberry Pi.

So far I have the button and the QT layout done:
[UI Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsGnJ.png)

I want to program the button to just open the RPi network settings, shown in this image:
[RPi Network settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXv0A.png)

I just have no idea what function to use to call this window to open.

```
class WirelessWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_WirelessWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.NetworkSettings.clicked.               #Cant figure out this line!

        # Close WirelessWindow
        self.Exit.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())
```